# How can I make an endless progressbar in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5

I don't know how long an action could take and I want to display a progress bar to the user in a dialog box. I've tried using System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar but it doesn't seem to support it.

An example of what I'd want is the progress bar that windows shows you when it's looking for new drivers on the internet. It's just got three or four 'bars' going back and forth marquee style on the progress bar.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar has a property called `Style`. Setting `Style` to `Marquee` will achieve the effect your looking for.

**EDIT:** [Divo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40347/divo) points out the Marquee [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style.aspx) is only available on

> Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003

The comments provide even more information indicating that this appears to work everywhere as long as you're using .NET 2.0 or higher.

Comment: Seems Microsoft can't let go of "marquee" entirely. :-D

Comment: Make that "Windows XP or higher". I've just tested on Windows Vista and Windows 7 Beta (both 64 bit, though) and it worked.

Comment: Note: This is a .NET 2.0+ feature. .NET 1.1 did not expose the style property.

Comment: As the question is tagged .net3.5 I think it's safe to assume the asking person won't try to use it in .NET 1.1

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried setting the `Style` property of the `System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar` to `Marquee`?

However, surprisingly, this property is only available on the following platforms (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style.aspx)):

> Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003

Might be that the documentation has not been updated to Vista though. Anyone knows about a limitation on Vista?

EDIT: As posted in another comment the documentation seems to be wrong with respect to the supported platforms. Should be working on Vista as well as Windows 7.

Answer (score 6):

Just use an animated gif :)

You can make your own here:
http://www.ajaxload.info/

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. I create a indeterminate progressbar for you. 
Add an custom control to your project/form and insert this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AnimatedCustomControls
{
  sealed class IndeterminateProgressbar : Control
  {
    private readonly List<int> positions = new List<int>();
    private readonly Timer tmrAnimation = new Timer {Interval = 5, Enabled = false};
    private readonly Timer tmrAddPosition = new Timer {Interval = 500, Enabled = true};


    public Color ProgressColor { get; set; }
    public Color InactiveColor { get; set; }

    public IndeterminateProgressbar()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        ProgressColor = Color.FromArgb(40, 190, 245);
        InactiveColor = Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40);
        tmrAnimation.Tick += tmrAnimation_Tick;
        tmrAddPosition.Tick += tmrAddPosition_Tick;
        if (!DesignMode) tmrAnimation.Start();
    }

    void tmrAddPosition_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        positions.Add(1);
    }

    void tmrAnimation_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignMode) tmrAnimation.Stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
        {
            positions[i] += 2 + Math.Abs(positions[i]) / 50;
            if (positions[i] > Width) positions.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
        if (Enabled)
        {
            positions.Clear();
            positions.AddRange(new[] { Width / 10, Width / 3, Width / 2, (int)(Width * 0.7) });
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Enabled)
        {
            e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
            foreach (int i in positions)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 4f), i, 0, i, Height);
            }
        }
        else e.Graphics.Clear(InactiveColor);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

}

You should then build your solution and when you go back to the designer, the new control should be in your toolbox. Drag it into you form, set the maximum and minimum value and that's all.

I've created a sample program to let you know how it is used:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        indeterminateProgressbar1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(40, 190, 245); //it's an nice color ;)
        indeterminateProgressbar1.Size = new Size(400, 4); //make it small in the height looks better
        indeterminateProgressbar1.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found Chris Lawl's solution the best, very good and clean solution just include a gif http://www.ajaxload.info/ and no mess creating never ending progress bar.

Comment: No mess creating never ending progress bar? All you have to do is setting the animation of marquee to 0 once finished and set the Visible property of the progressbar to false. Its no magic.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but one way is just to set Value back to 0 when it reaches the end (assuming your task isn't complete)

Comment: I feel physical pain every time I see a program doing that. From a usability POV, this is among the worst things a lazy programmer can do. It is uninformative, wrong, distracting, annoying and diminishing user trust in the "progress bar"-metaphor as a whole. Even no progress bar at all is better.

Comment: Agreed. Probably the best solution for a long-running process for which no progress information can ever be obtained (the question was a bit unclear), would be no progress bar at all ... but hey, he asked how to get an indeterminate one :)

Comment: Seems like I misread the desired effect.  That was the only infinite progress bar that I could remember off the top of my head.

Comment: No progress bar is definitely worse if it's going to be long (say more than 10-30 seconds depending on the patience of the person and how slow they expect their computer to be.  I usually consider killing a process after 30 seconds of no progress indication

Comment: @Davy8: I've always liked the idea of a logo (i.e. an analogue clock abstraction) that rotates a bit when something happens ("file copied" event or such). If many things happen it rotates fast, if few things happen, it rotates slowly. If the process is dead, it does not rotate at all.

Comment: Also "no progress bar"does not equal "no indication that the process id doing something". You can still switch the cursor to a busy one, tell the user what you do, etc. But a progress bar is not the ideal idiom if you have a process where you can't estimate completion or progress.