# Implementing a progress bar while adding rows to datatable

Tags: c#

I have written a code to transfer values in a text file to a datatable. As the number of records are high, I have implemented a progress bar to view the status. But it throws an error called

> *"Value of '1' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between
>   'minimum' and 'maximum'."*

Can you please help me to implement the progress bar successfully within the loop. Here is the code that i use:

I have updated my coding with backgroundworker. But it throws an error called:

"Error creating window handle"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;            

        if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text=thisDialog.FileName;
            string file1 = textBox1.Text;
            //background worker
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            } 
            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(file1))
            {           
                string line=String.Empty;
                int lineno = 0;                    

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("DISKXFER"))
                    {
                        string dataLine = line.ToString();
                        string[] split = dataLine.Split(',');
                        int result = split.Length;
                        if (lineno == 0)
                        {
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                DataColumn dcss = new DataColumn(x.ToString(), Type.GetType("System.String"));
                                dt.Columns.Add(dcss);
                            }
                            if (dt.Rows.Count <= lineno)
                            {
                                dr = dt.NewRow();
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);                                    
                            }
                            dr = dt.Rows[lineno];                                
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                dr[x+1] = split[x];
                            }                                
                        }                                
                        else
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows.Count <= lineno)
                            {
                                dr = dt.NewRow();
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);                                    
                            }
                            dr = dt.Rows[lineno];                               
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                dr[x+1] = split[x];
                            }

                        }                            
                        lineno += 1;                        

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    } 

 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
        string line;
        string file1 = textBox1.Text;
        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(file1))
        {
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("DISKXFER"))
                {
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(count);
                }
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Comment: On which line throws this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your application not to be in a "not responding" state while you loop in the lines then you can use a background worker. BUT be careful. The file dialog must be outside the thread so as not to have any cross thread exceptions! Save the file path to a private field and use it in your background worker. Every time that you store a line then use the ReportProgress so as to update the progress bar!!
Take a sample about using Background Worker:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

if (bw.IsBusy != true)
 {
      bw.RunWorkerAsync();
 }
 if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
  {
      bw.CancelAsync();
  }
 private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){ }
 private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e){ }
 private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e){ }
```

**EDIT:**

```
private string file1;
private DataTable dt;
private int iTotalLinesOfFile;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if(dt==null) 
            {
                dt== new DataTable();
            }
            else
            {
                dt.Clear();
            }
            file1 = thisDialog.FileName;
            textBox1.Text=file1;

            iTotalLinesOfFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1).Length;
            //background worker
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); //when you call this the DoWork will start and the code will continue!!
            }
            //do not let the user to click the button again!!
            button1.Enabled = false;
            //you will use this code if you want to cancel the job that Worker does.
            //if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            //{
            //    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            //} 

        }
    } 

 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {   
        DataRow dr = null;   
        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(file1))
            {           
                string line=String.Empty;
                int lineno = 0;                    
                int count = 0;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("DISKXFER"))
                    {
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(count);
                        string dataLine = line.ToString();
                        string[] split = dataLine.Split(',');
                        int result = split.Length;
                        if (lineno == 0)
                        {
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                DataColumn dcss = new DataColumn(x.ToString(), Type.GetType("System.String"));
                                dt.Columns.Add(dcss);
                            }
                            if (dt.Rows.Count <= lineno)
                            {
                                dr = dt.NewRow();
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);                                    
                            }
                            dr = dt.Rows[lineno];                                
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                dr[x+1] = split[x];
                            }                                
                        }                                
                        else
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows.Count <= lineno)
                            {
                                dr = dt.NewRow();
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);                                    
                            }
                            dr = dt.Rows[lineno];                               
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                dr[x+1] = split[x];
                            }

                        }                            
                        lineno += 1;                        

                    }
                    count += 1;
                }

            }
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int iCount = e.ProgressPercentage;
        if(iTotalLinesOfFile==0) return;
        //progressBar1.Value must not be less than 0 and more than 100
        progressBar1.Value = (iCount / iTotalLinesOfFile) * 100;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried to use this code but it throws an error called "Error creating window handle". I have updated my question with the new codings.

Comment: I will edit my post. Check the code and tell me! In your code you loop twice in your file so I changed it. Be careful it;s not a good practice to loop twice in a file when you can do it in one loop!

Comment: hi. i was able to get what i want with the help of your code. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

**progressBar1.maximum is set to zero at the moment!**

- **Option 1:** Define maximum of the progressBar1.

  progressBar1.Maximum = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Length;
- **Option 2:** Use [Endlessprogressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635958/how-can-i-make-an-endless-progressbar-in-winforms) to reach your goal.

**Edit: Included corrected Code of option 1:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;

        if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text=thisDialog.FileName;
            string file1 = textBox1.Text;
            progressBar1.Maximum = File.ReadAllLines(file1).Length;
            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(file1))
            {           
                string line=String.Empty;
                int lineno = 0;                    

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("DISKXFER"))
                    {
                        string dataLine = line.ToString();
                        string[] split = dataLine.Split(',');
                        int result = split.Length;
                        if (lineno == 0)
                        {
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                DataColumn dcss = new DataColumn(x.ToString(), Type.GetType("System.String"));
                                dt.Columns.Add(dcss);
                            }
                            if (dt.Rows.Count <= lineno)
                            {
                                dr = dt.NewRow();
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);                                    
                            }
                            dr = dt.Rows[lineno];                                
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                dr[x+1] = split[x];
                            }                                
                        }                                
                        else
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows.Count <= lineno)
                            {
                                dr = dt.NewRow();
                                dt.Rows.Add(dr);                                    
                            }
                            dr = dt.Rows[lineno];                               
                            for (int x = 0; x < result; x++)
                            {
                                dr[x+1] = split[x];
                            }

                        }
                        progressBar1.Value = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr);
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        lineno += 1;                        

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

As others already pointed out: Backgroundworker would be a better option. Especially if your UI still needs to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, at the time you assign this there is no row in the datatable, thus the maximum is 0.

```
progressBar1.Maximum = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Anyway, as you don't seem to know the number of rows in advance, it doesn't make any sense to display any "progress" because it would always be full as you extend the maximum. You could use marquee mode however. Or initialize the maximum beforehand with the number of rows you're going to add.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your [`ProgressBar.Maximum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx) and [`ProgressBar.Minimum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.minimum.aspx) properties which range do you want.

This properties gets or sets the maximum and maximum values of the range of the control. Their default values `0` and `100`.

For `Minimum` property;

> This property specifies the lower limit of the Value property. When
>   the value of the Minimum property is changed, the ProgressBar control
>   is redrawn to reflect the new range of the control. When the value of
>   the Value property is equal to the value of the Minimum property, the
>   progress bar is empty. To change the value of the progress bar, use
>   the Step property with the PerformStep method, use the Increment
>   method, or set the value of the Value property directly.